# How to implement a helper in Symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, helper

I'd like to create my own helper but can't find any help on Google for Symfony 1.4/Doctrine.

I guess it has something to do with creating a `myClassHelper.class.php` in `lib/helpers/` or something, but I don't know what to implement, or if specific methods have to be overridden.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Helpers in symfony 1.4 are not classes — they're just functions

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't think that anything changed regarding the helpers in 1.4. From the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_helpers)(although 1.2):

> Helper functions (regular PHP functions returning HTML code) should be saved in a file called `FooBarHelper.php`, where FooBar is the name of the helper group. Store the file in the `apps/myapp/lib/helper/` directory (or in any `helper/` directory created under one of the `lib/` folders of your project) so it can be found automatically by the `use_helper('FooBar')` helper for inclusion.

So you just put normal functions in a normal file (has nothing to do with classes or methods). The functions can take arbitrary parameters (you decide what they need to create the HTML) and the have to return HTML.

E.g.

**MyHelper.php**

```
function hello_word() {
   return '<strong>Hello world!</strong>';
}
```

and in the template:

```
<?php use_helper('My') ?>

<!-- somewhere in the template -->
<?php echo hello_world() ?>
```

Comment: thanks, haha.. it slipped my mind that my helper function was returning a string, but my template was simply calling the helper function without echo'ing it :)