# How to create/use custom classes and helper in symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

What is the best way to put custom library or helper methods in symfony? 
I am using doctrine with my project. One place I consider to put is under

```
project_root/lib/vendor/MyClasses/
```

But if I want to create a class or helper function which will use some core symfony/doctrine methods and return a result then how to do that and where should I put it?
I want it to call from different modules to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for the custom library part of the question, you might probably want to put your external library into the *lib/vendor* folder. Since symfony doesn't automatically load everything that's in there, you'll have to tell its autoloader to do so.

You can either extend your *config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php* (as described [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Propel/en/16#chapter_16_sending_emails)) or (and this is the much simpler and cleaner way) you add them to your *config/autoload.yml* (you might have to create this one).
For the latter option, [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/19-Mastering-Symfony-s-Configuration-Files#chapter_19_extending_the_autoloading_feature) is a great place to start looking at.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Both of your links pointing to the same url. Can you please check. 
So putting it inside any of the lib/ directory will autoload the classes? But do I need to extend my custom classes from any symfony/doctrine classes to have them able to access doctrine/symfony core features?

Comment: @medhad Link 1 fixed. No, as I mentioned, _/lib/vendor/_ is the best place to put your external libraries, but with the standard config, only the _lib/vendor/symfony_ folder is being autoloaded (see above). If you want to make use of symfony functionality, you might want to look into wrapping both up into a plugin. A bit of googleing will certainly take you further.

Comment: Just adding my findings so it may help others who are reading this!
After trying different approaches what I have found that it is also possible to use a class by creating or putting it inside the **app/lib/** directory(app specific) or **app/module/lib** directory(for module specific) of your Symfony project. Symfony will automatically load the classes and you can call those from your action. You may extend it from sfActions or not; but doing so you will be able to access some core features like `sfContext::getInstance()` and similar other class methods and properties.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149091/how-to-implement-a-helper-in-symfony-1-4).

As asked in [symfony's 1.2](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_helpers) "Definitive Guide" docs :

> Helper functions (regular PHP functions returning HTML code) should be saved in a file called FooBarHelper.php, where FooBar is the name of the helper group. Store the file in the apps/myapp/lib/helper/ directory (or in any helper/ directory created under one of the lib/ folders of your project) so it can be found automatically by the use_helper('FooBar') helper for inclusion.

So, if you want to create custom helper **FooBar** for foo() function, create file **lib/helper/FooBarHelper.php** :

```
function foo() {echo "foo!"; }
```

to use it in your template:

```
use_helper('FooBar')
....

foo(); //outs "foo!"
```

Comment: But how can I use it from the module action not from view. Suppose I want to get a variable returned by Class/helper method containing the result set. It seems helper can be called from the template only and it must generate some html output. I want to create a class with some method that I can call from different module action. Which class to extend and where to put it?