# include file in action.class.php ? symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i have library in file Example.php. I would like this include for action.class.php. How can i make this?
In template i can make partial and use include_partial, but how can make somethings in action?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212649/how-to-create-use-custom-classes-and-helper-in-symfony-1-4/5217161#5217161)

Answer (score 0):

An easy - and symfony like - way would be to make a class file and store it in the **lib** directory, so the symfony autoloader will provide them all over your project.

Example.class.php :

```
Class Example {
    static public function myFoo(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

actions.class.php :

```
public function executeFoo($request){
    /* snip */
    $this->foo = Example::myFoo();
    /* snip */
}
```