# Best way to load external library in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I've searched a lot how to load/include a simple class in symfony 1.4 and i found nothing. I have this situation.

Under:

```
./apps/APP_NAME/
    modules/MOD_NAME/lib
```

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
   function get_data(){
      retrun "data";
   }
}
```

- Which is the best way to load in controller on symfony 1.4 the class?
- Over on config exist some other way like function use_helper()?

**Update:** I want to load on demand, not to autoload with the convention of symfony 1.4 naming the file MyClass.class.php

Comment: Is there some reason you can't `require 'MyClass.php';` the file and `use MyClass;` it? Not using the autoloader is a weird decision though.

Comment: The problem of require || require_once is that are not flexible on module env. For example when i call use_helper() as second argument i can specify the module.

Answer (score 1):

Is not the best but a first version that work under module ENV is:

```
    function load_module_lib($module, $name_file) {
       require_once (sfContext::getInstance()->getModuleDirectory() . '/../' . $module . '/lib/' . $name_file . '.class.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **This file allows you to define extra classes that can be autoloaded when Symfony loads. and Symfony allows you to place php code inside a `.yml` file**

```
##apps/appName/config/autoload.yml
autoload:
  makeupaname:
    name: Make up a name
    path: <?php echo $mydynamicvar; ?>/someFolder/
    recursive: on
   
  makeupasecondname:
    name: Make up a second name
    path: <?php echo $mydynamicvar; ?>someOtherFolder/
    recursive: on
```

as well as go thorough this extra links [autoloading namespaces in symfony 1.4](http://www.slaubi.com/using-namespaces-in-symfony-1-4) and [How to create/use custom classes and helper in symfony 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212649/how-to-create-use-custom-classes-and-helper-in-symfony-1-4)

**Edit 01**

> If you want to place externel library you have to place that in `lib/vendor` folder. You cant create that inside `app` folder.
>
> As well as if you just add new library to that and site will not load your library. So that only you have to use the `autoload` file to do that

This article help you out. [Loading external libraries for **symfony 2**](http://www.masnun.com/2012/03/03/symfony2-loading-old-external-libraries.html)

Comment: This seems like the proper solution in a normal use case, but the question specifically calls out for _not_ using the autoloader and instead allowing the class to load to on demand - which I'm not sure this solution does.